# Userinput in Textbox overwrites Databinding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, command

I have a working `OneWay` DataBinding from a double `CLRProperty` to a `Texttbox.Text.` I don't use a `TwoWay` because not every userinput is acceptable. BTW I use an existing `Command` that impements the `ICommand` interface.

The problem as soon as the user types in a text in the `Textbox`, the `Databinding` is destroyed.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=myDouble, Converter={converter:DoubleToTextConverter}, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "destroyed"? The user input will override the source property value at least until the source is updated again by another way, this is expected behavior.

Comment: whats the `ICommand` got to do with this? Also if not every user input is valid use a form of [Input Validation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15239/Validation-in-Windows-Presentation-Foundation) or ignore applying the new `value` in the property `setter`?

Comment: @Pragmateek With "destroyed" I mean that when the source property updates the text in the textbox doesn't update. (It did work perfectly fine just till the user change the text)

Comment: @Viv. The Command is used several times in the program already. I just add a new way for the user to use it. So I allredy have the CanExecute function, that test the input.

Comment: @MartinHoratschek All I meant was your question shows no command on the `TextBox` hence wasn't sure where or what this command is being used for.

Comment: it would be much easier if you take a string property with twoway binding in your viewmodel, validate the input with idataerrorinfo and cast to double when set the value to your model (this way you get rid of the converter too). Binding with mode OneWay are "readonly" so you can just update the text from your source.

Answer (score 0):

How should your programm know if the user input is acceptable or not, if you dont tell him?
To check the user input, you could do the following:

- Use [DataValidation](http://wpftutorial.net/DataValidation.html) to accept only certain inputs.
- Create a second TextBox where the user does the input and if it's ok (you check that in your ViewModel), you apply it to the first TextBox's binded Property `myDouble`.

Comment: My programm knows if the value is acceptable. The ICommand has a `bool CanExecute(object Parameter){...}` method. So if the value is not correct, the button who "uses" the Command is not usable when the input is not viable. My problem is who to get the databinding working, not the input validation.

Comment: This wont work the way you want it. But you could f.e. use a label to display the value (Binding Mode=OneWay) and a TextBox to let the user type the value in (Binding Mode=OneWayToSource).